# Wordpress custom post types not showing in search

Tags: php, wordpress, search, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to get custom post types and advanced custom fields to show in my search results. At the moment it only searches the default posts.

I have created my custom post types with this plugin: [Custom Post Type UI](http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/)

I'm using advanced custom field plugin: [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/)

Here is my code:

**search.php**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="hakusanalla">
    <h1 class="page-title"><?php printf( __( 'Tulokset haulle: %s', 'nothing' ), '' .           get_search_query() . '' ); ?></h1>  
</div>
<ul id="post-list">
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>  

    <?php
        $featured = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_thumbnail_id',true);
        $attachments = get_children( 'post_type=attachment&orderby=menu_order&exclude='.$featured.'&post_mime_type=image&post_parent='.$post->ID );
        $vimeo = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rw_post-vimeo',true);
        ?>

    <div class="hakutulos">              
        <li class="post">
        <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>    
        <span class="entry-published">
        <div class="hakudate">
            <time datetime="<?php the_time('Y-m-d')?>"><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></time>
        </div>
        <?php the_excerpt(__('(more…)')); ?>

            <?php  get_template_part( 'includes/inc-image' ); ?>
            <p><?php  get_template_part( 'includes/inc-detail' ); ?></p>

        </li> 
    </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>

<section id="pagination">
    <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?> 
</section>
<?php else : ?>
<div class="errorlaatikko">
    <h1><?php _e( 'Ei tuloksia', 'blankslate' ); ?></h1>
    <p><?php _e( 'Hakemaasi sivua ei löytynyt. Tarkista oikeinkirjoitus tai kokeile hakua.', 'twentyten' ); ?></p>
    <div class="errorhaku">  
    <?php get_search_form(); ?> 
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**searchform.php**

```
<?php $search_text = "haku"; ?>
    <form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $search_text; ?>"  
        name="s" id="search-form"  
        onblur="javascript: if( this.value != 'search') { this.value = 'search';    this.style.color = '#fff'; }"  
     onclick="javascript: if( this.value == 'search') { this.value = ''; this.style.color = '#fff'; }"
    ) 
        {this.value = '';}" />
        <input placeholder="Etsi" type="submit" id="searchsubmit"/>
    </form>
```

**searchpage.php**

```
<?php
/**
* Template Name: Search Page
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php
    global $query_string;
    $query_args = explode("&", $query_string);
    $search_query = array();

    foreach($query_args as $key => $string) {
        $query_split = explode("=", $string);
        $search_query[$query_split[0]] = urldecode($query_split[1]);
    } // foreach

    $search = new WP_Query($search_query);
?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Does anybody know how to fix this problem?

Best regards,

Johanna

Comment: I'm not familiar with Custom Post Type UI, but I use Types for my custom post types, which has a setting to make the custom post type "searchable". So I would check your plugin for a setting like that?

Answer (score 0):

Put these when you define your custom post type

```
'query_var' => true,
'exclude_from_search' => false,
```

I think Custom Post type ui have the option.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I change query var and exclude from search like you said but still not working... I also tried to use this Types plugin but it isn't working either.